# How the Bloch sphere of a Hahn echo in NMR looks like? 90-t-90-t-echo

Tags: nuclear-physics, magnetic-fields, reference-frames, bloch-oscillation

I have tried to find in the literature a proper nice and beautiful Bloch sphere to describe the trajectory of a nuclear spin, starting in z-axis, using a pulse sequence of an initial 90º pulse with zero phase (which means that the pulse is launched in the x-axis), wait for a time $\tau$, and then launch another 90º pulse with zero phase, and wait the same amount of time tau to measure an echo.

Please notice that I am talking about Nuclear Magnetic resonance, and most of  the books don't offer a Bloch sphere to explain this echo, which is supposed to be the first! echo, and only use a 90º and 180º  pulse to explain that.

I have read the original article of Hahn echo, but I saw that his diagram is not clear.

Comment: The standard Hahn echo is 90°-$\tau$-180° then echo. If you only use a pair of 90° pulses then you're only describing the original Ramsey setup which is 90°-$\tau$-90°-test.

Comment: In the NMR jargon this setup is know as Hanh echo http://www.wmf.univ.szczecin.pl/~sergeev/Dydaktyka/Pr-R/Hahn-spin-echo.pdf becuase of historic reasons, but I did not imply this should be called in this way. Now back to the question, I think I will try to find the Bloch sphere as the Ramsey set up instead, any suggestions?